# Insert rows in mysql from dynamic array seperated by multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

[image]I have a mysql table which have columns like:

```
Healthcare_Provider_Taxonomy_Code_1, 
Healthcare_Provider_Taxonomy_Code_2,
Healthcare_Provider_Taxonomy_Code_3, .....
```

I am calling an API which returns result in json and after decoding,I got an array ---

```
Array
(
[result_count] => 1
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [taxonomies] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [state] => CO
                                [code] => 111N00000X
                                [primary] => 
                                [license] => EL.2786416
                                [desc] => Chiropractor
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [state] => CO
                                [code] => 111N00000X
                                [primary] => 1
                                [license] => CHR.0007308
                                [desc] => Chiropractor
                            )

                    )
```

The Place where I stuck is, the returned array may be dynamic, e.g--the taxonomy array may be two or one or three. How would I insert that into mysql table with seperated columns as described above?

Basically it would insert like

```
ROW 1 ---- 111N00000X------111N00000X.
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please include the table structure where you will insert the data?

Comment: just treat that API like any normal array that you got, just connect to db, traverse the array, make insertion, thats it

Comment: @LeeBalino I have added the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the API you are querying has a maximum number of records and you have a sufficient number of columns to sotre them all, you could use :

```
$number_of_col = 4;

$codes = array_fill(0, $number_of_col, null);   // Create a container of know length
$params = array_replace($codes, array_column($data, 'code'));  // Extract eh code column and overwrite the container

$query = "INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";    // Query with fixed number of columns
$stmnt = $pdo->$prepare($query);

$stmnt->execute($codes, $params);
```

The function [array_column](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php) has been added since PHP 5.5.0, so you might not have access to it. In that case, you can do the work with a simple foreach.

```
$codes = array_fill(0, $number_of_col, null);   // Create a container of know length
foreach ($result['taxonomie'] as $key => $sub_array)
    $codes[$key] = $sub_array['code'];

// Insert in DB just like show before. Your data is in $codes
```

Also, a piece of advice when dealing with API from my experience. Never ever assume that a certain result has been provided. In my examples I purposely omitted to check if the result existed before using them, but you should.

```
$codes = array_fill(0, $number_of_col, null);   // Create a container of know length
if (!isset($result['taxonomie']))
// Error handling

foreach ($result['taxonomie'] as $key => $sub_array)
{
    if (!isset($sub_array['code']))
        // Error handling
    $codes[$key] = $sub_array['code'];
}
```

Finally, if you do not know the maximum number of result your query to the API will return, then you cannot set a fixed number of column in your database. You will need a structure where 1 code = 1 row.

Hope it helps